# looking to compare against column number 3 of row number 3 using awk

Tags: awk

looking to compare against column number 3 of row number 3 using awk

input:

```
uniqueid 22618
remoteid remote1
established 1302
```

output:

```
22618
```

Tried:

```
awk '{ if(established > 1000) print 22618}'
```

Comment: Sonu jaiswal, good that you have showed your efforts, also try to post all your conditions of your question with sample input and sample output too, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest:

```
awk '$1=="uniqueid" {uid=$2}; $1=="established" {est=$2}; est>1000 {print uid}' file
```

Output:

```
22618
```

- If column 1 contains `uniqueid` save value of column 2 to variable `uid`.
- If column 1 contains `established` save value of column 2 to variable `est`.
- If value in variable `est` is larger 1000 print value in variable `uid`.

Answer (score 1):

*to compare against column number 3 of row number 3 using awk* you need to specify the record (`NR==3`) and the field (`$2` probably, not `$3`):

```
$ awk  'NR==3 && $2 > 1000{ print 22618 }' file
22618
```